# Access methods of member of Parent that references other module, from child

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to Python. Apologies for the title. Been searching for days on this problem :S

I am coming from a PHP background where I can create classes in their own files and then call those classes from anywhere as long as I have a reference to them.

For instance;

- require class Z from class A.
- Then have class B extend class A.
- then be able to call methods on class Z from class B.

I want to have a parent class that contains methods and members that other classes can extend so that I'm not re-inventing the wheel every time I want create a class that is distinct in its own way, but also has similarities to other classes.

Maybe my understanding of how modules work in Python is wrong? Following is an example of what I'm trying to achieve. Do i need all of these classes in one module? Can someone explain the process for what I'm attempting to do?

```
import Z

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.varZ = Z()
        self.some_value = None

    def a_setter_function(self, value):
        self.some_value = value
```

Then extending classes, for example class B through to class X;

```
import A

class B(A):
    def some_function(self):
        something = self.varZ.do_something_from_z_class()

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.a_setter_function(value)
```

Always raises;

```
'ClassB' object has no attribute 'varZ'
```

I have no issues in calling 'a_setter_function()' from class B.

Can also call methods on varZ from class A.

The only solution I can come up with is to have a method in class A (called from class B) which calls the method from class Z. ie The method I'm trying to call from Class B.

Why can't I call a method of class Z from class B via its parent class A?

Comment: `import A` then `class B(A)` won't work, as `A` is a module object. Same for `import Z` and `self.varZ = Z()`; module objects are not callable.

Comment: Generally speaking, what you are trying to do just works. Apart from the problems I pointed out, the code would *not actually raise an `AttributeError`*. It appears you have oversimplified your problem here and inadvertently made the problem go away.

Comment: I've changed my wording of the question. I simply don't have a good enough understanding of how to approach the problem I face, from a Python perspective.